# placing an element wherever drag ends

Tags: javascript

I have some issues with placing my element wherever drag ends. I cant find the exact position (left and top) of the place where user drop the element.

```
//html code

<div class="box1">
      <div id="item-1" class="item">1</div>
      <div id="item-2" class="item" draggable="true" ondragend="dragEnd(event)">2</div>
      <div id="item-3" class="item">3</div>
      <div id="item-4" class="item">4</div>
    </div>
    <div id="box-2" class="box2" ondragover="dragOver(event)" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragenter="dragEnter(event)" ondragleave="dragLeave(event)"></div>



//javascript code

function dragEnd2(event){
 event.target.style.position = "absolute";
 let top = ???
 let left = ???
 event.target.style.top = `${top}px`;
 event.target.style.left = `${left}px`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the mouse position on `event.client.X` and `event.client.Y` with `mousemove` event.

```js
const box = document.getElementById('box')

// Define a flag
let isSelectingElement = false;

// Enable dragging for this element on 'mousedown' and 'mouseup'
box.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
    isSelectingElement = true;
})
box.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
    isSelectingElement = false;
})

// Get mouse X and Y position and update element position based on that
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
    if (isSelectingElement) {
        box.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`
        box.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`
    }
})
```

```css
#box {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: blueviolet;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div id="box" class="box"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need to use dragend event plus, I want to move the element item-2 to the box-2. Sorry I didn't mention that.